# What are the steps in showing $3^{ \log_2 x} = x^{\log_2 3}$

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

Formatted:

$$3^{\log_2 x} = x^{\log_2 3}$$

I know that $\log_2 x = \frac{\log_3 x}{\log_3 2}$ and that $3^{\log_3 x} = 
x$; but how would the $\frac{1}{\log_3 2}$ part of the exponent fit in?

What are the properties involved?

Comment: You may take the $log$ base $2$ on both sides. By one of the most well known log properties, you get on both sides of the equal sign a product of.....two equal terms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing where you left off just for the sake of it (taking $\log_2$ of both sides is a lot simpler), we currently have:

$$x^{1/\log_3(2)} = x^{\log_2(3)}$$

We know that:

$${1 \over \log_3(2)} = {\log_3(3) \over \log_3(2)} = \log_2(3)$$

Which gives the desired exponent.

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessary to change base. You just take the $\log_2$ of both sides and apply the properties of logarithms. You get
$$\log_2 3\cdot \log_2 x = \log_2 3\cdot \log_2 x,$$
which is true for any $x > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray*}
3^{\log_2(x)}=2^{\log_2(3^{\log_2(x)})}= 2^{\log_2(3) \log_2(x)}=2^{\log_2(x^{\log_2(3)})}=x^{\log_2(3)}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: There should be no exponent in exponents.

Answer (score 1):

original equation:
$$3^{\log_2 x} = x^{\log_2 3}$$
take $\log_2$ of both sides:
$$\log_2 (3^{\log_2 x}) = \log_2 (x^{\log_2 3})$$
use exponent rules:
$$\log_2 x \log_2 3 = \log_2 3 \log_2 x$$
we know that $\log_2 3 = \log_2 3$, and that $\log_2 x = \log_2 x$; we also know that $xy = xy$; thus we know that the above is true.